# initializing array with variable

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, size

I'm having an issue  initializing std::array with variable.

```
std::string str = "Hello world this is just testing";

int size = str.size();

std::array<char, size> arr;
```

Returns following error:

```
note: 'int size' is not const
error: the value od 'size' is not usable in a constant expression
note: in template argument for type 'long long unsigned int'
```

I'm newbie, please help.

Comment: Just like for plain C-style arrays, the size must be a compile-time constant (this is actually a requirement for all template value arguments). If you want an "array" whose size is known only at run-time you must use `std::vector`.

Comment: I'm also very curious why you need an array (or vector) with the same size as an existing string? What is the use of the array (or vector)? What problem is it supposed to solve? Can't you use the string itself?

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude, I couldn't think of std::vector, saved my time.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. I'm coding dns protocol packet stuff and i need to inject some string domainname as array like. Idk

Comment: Why do you want this? Use the string itself as the array

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili crafting manually dns packet/protocol stuff

Comment: As long as you're working with text, use `std::string`. Everything you can do with a `std::vector`, you can also do with a `std::string`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude got it, my pleasure

Comment: @DennisEarlyman You probably don't need to use neither `std::array` nor `std::vector`. You can see `std::string` as a dynamic array of char (this is what it owns internally). Just use it directly.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use variables as template arguments unless they are compile time constant. Hence, the size of `std::array` must be compile time constant. What you're trying to do is not possible. Same limitation applies to array variables as well.

`std::string` already internally owns a dynamic array of `char`, so you probably don't need `std::array` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a `constant expression` as the size to the array data structure. If you want to assign variable length to a data structure, you can use `std::vector<char> v(size);` instead of an array.
I also think you can use variable length with arrays if you use the [`GCC` compiler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html)

Comment: Thank you, I'll work with vector now.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also add elements to the vector on the fly :
`
for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++) v.push_back(str[i]);
`

Comment: `const` is not sufficient. With a constant `size` there would be same error: https://godbolt.org/z/3oTzs9aze

Comment: You can't assign a `non-constant` to a `constant` value either. 
You can only assign a number directly to a constant, for example: 
`const int N = 10;`

Comment: hm? `int x = 42; const int y = x;` and `const int a = 42; int b = a;` are both completely fine. I suppose you actually mean a constant expression that can be evaluated at compile time. `const` isnt that

Comment: Yes, you are right; I should have said `constant expression`. Sorry if it wasn't clear.